# How can I read files from directory and send as JSON to client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I have logs files in server directory i wanted to display file names to client side so i have created `readDirectory.js` that is reading names correctly Now i am very new to `node.js` and i am trying to send `json` data to client but its not happening, How can i send log files name to client using express ?

readDirectory.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './Logs'
var Logs = [];
function readDirectory(){
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
        Logs.push(items);
       /* console.log(items);
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            console.log(items[i]);
        }*/

    });
 return Logs;
}
exports.readDirectory = readDirectory;
```

app.js

```
 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var readDirectory = require('./readDirectory');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

    app.get('/logs',function(req,res){
    res.send(readDirectory.readDirectory());
   });
```

angularFactory.js

```
angular.module('App').factory('DitFactory', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    var data;
    return {
        data:"data from factory"
       getLogs: function () {
            return $http.get('/logs')
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your **readDirectory.js** should look like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './Logs'
var Logs = [];
function readDirectory(callback){
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
       Logs.push(items);
       callback(Logs);       
    }); 
}
exports.readDirectory = readDirectory;
```

and your **app.js** should be like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var readDirectory = require('./readDirectory');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/logs',function(req,res){
    readDirectory.readDirectory(function(logFiles){
       res.json({files : logFiles});
   });
});
```

Hope this Help !

Answer (score 2):

You have to put serialize the `Logs` array into json and send it back to client

```
app.get('/logs',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(readDirectory.readDirectory()));
});
```

Or

```
app.get('/logs',function(req,res){
    res.json(readDirectory.readDirectory());
});
```

Comment: still i do not see data i am not sure why

Comment: Try to use the web browser to access the JSON then? Or you can try `console.log(response)`

Comment: i think first place i am not getting data from `readDirectory.js` to `app.js` for some reason i debuged it and i see 4 items in Logs array in `readDirectory` function but its not being passed to `app.js`

Comment: Did you debug the line `var readDirectory = require('./readDirectory');` in app.js

Comment: `Server.connections property is deprecated. Use Server.getConnections method instead.` it is calling the function `readDirectory` but its not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

Since Node v11.0.0 you can use `require('fs').promises` to get promises.

In your case you are pushing the array of the files in the directory into "Logs" array. Since in this case "Logs" will always be an array with only one value, I didn't use it.

You can do it like this:

```
var fs = require('fs').promises;
var path = './Logs'
async function readDirectory() {
    const files = await fs.readdir(path);
    return files;
}
```

In order to return the list of files in the folder change your app.js like this:

```
app.get('/logs', function (req, res) {
    readDirectory.readDirectory()
        .then((files) => {
            res.send(files);
        });
});
```

Link for the full answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821924/8021938

Source:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I've just added the answer for this case, hope it helps.