# How to read file with async/await properly?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, readfile

I cannot figure out how `async`/`await` works. I slightly understand it but I can't make it work.

```js
function loadMonoCounter() {
    fs.readFileSync("monolitic.txt", "binary", async function(err, data) {
       return await new Buffer( data);
  });
}

module.exports.read = function() {
  console.log(loadMonoCounter());
};
```

I know, I could use `readFileSync`, but if I do, I know I'll never understand `async`/`await` and I'll just bury the issue.

Goal: Call `loadMonoCounter()` and return the content of a file.

That file is incremented every time `incrementMonoCounter()` is called (every page load). The file contains the dump of a buffer in binary and is stored on a SSD.

No matter what I do, I get an error or `undefined` in the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using filesystem in node.js with async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593875/using-filesystem-in-node-js-with-async-await)

Answer (score 234, accepted):

To use `await`/`async` you need methods that return promises. The core API functions don't do that without wrappers like [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

// Convert fs.readFile into Promise version of same    
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

function getStuff() {
  return readFile('test');
}

// Can't use `await` outside of an async function so you need to chain
// with then()
getStuff().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

As a note, `readFileSync` does not take a callback, it returns the data or throws an exception. You're not getting the value you want because that function you supply is ignored and you're not capturing the actual return value.

Comment: The core API pre-dates the modern Promise specification and the adoption of `async`/`await`, so that's a necessary step. The good news is `promisify` usually makes it work with no mess.

Comment: This handles the mess of not being able to leverage async-await with FS normally. Thank you for this! You saved me a ton! There is no answer that really addresses this like yours.

Comment: Also await is kinda redundant since it can be infered. Only if you do want to explicitly have await in example, you can do `const file = await readFile...; return file;`.

Comment: @tadman do we still need to promisify in latest version of node?

Comment: @shijin Until the Node core API switches over to promises, which is unlikely at this point, then yes. There are NPM wrappers that do it for you, though.

Answer (score 483):

Since Node v11.0.0 fs promises are available natively without `promisify`:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
async function loadMonoCounter() {
    const data = await fs.readFile("monolitic.txt", "binary");
    return Buffer.from(data);
}
```

Comment: As of 21-Oct-2019, v12 is an active LTS version

Comment: `import { promises as fs } from "fs";` if you want to use import syntax.

Comment: A note on this approach, while it is clean, it also doesn't import other useful features of `fs` outside of the `fs.promises` api. It may be important to import `fs` separately from `fs.promises`.

Comment: I'm getting a weird response with this: Buffer(18524) [60, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 32, 116, 110, 116, 45, 108, 105, 98, 62, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 47, 42, 42, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 42, 32, 67, 111, 112, 121, 114,, …] what could it be?

Comment: Once you have the Buffer, you can convert it to a string using Buffer's method  `toString()` like `bufferData.toString()` - see the [docs for Buffer](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_buffer_tostring.asp).

Comment: Hint: call `await fs.readFile("monolitic.txt", "utf8");` to get the file content as a string

Comment: I like `const fs = require('fs/promises');` a bit more :)

Comment: Use `return Buffer.from(data)` or another alternative to avoid (node:76590) [DEP0005] warning.

Comment: so complicated, took me 1hr to see that you need to import `require('fs').promises`

Answer (score 65):

This is TypeScript version of @Joel's answer. It is usable after Node 11.0:

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

async function loadMonoCounter() {
    const data = await fs.readFile('monolitic.txt', 'binary');
    return Buffer.from(data);
}
```

Comment: ['binary' mangles the data. Don't use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441727/309483)

Answer (score 52):

You can use `fs.promises` available natively since Node v11.0.0

```
import fs from 'fs';

const readFile = async filePath => {
  try {
    const data = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
    return data
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you only want to use promises, you could do something like `const fs = require('fs').promises`

Comment: @nathanfranke this is not using import

Comment: For import you can do `import { promises } from "fs"`

Answer (score 34):

You can easily wrap the readFile command with a promise like so:

```
async function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

then use:

```
await readFile("path/to/file");
```

Comment: Isn't await used inside async function?

Comment: @VikasBhat Yes, the await line above would be used inside another async function as the spec requires it to be so.

Comment: You're missing a return on the `if (err)` path.

Comment: Is it must to write async function at start ?

Answer (score 27):

From node v14.0.0

```
const {readFile} = require('fs/promises');

const myFunction = async()=>{
    const result = await readFile('monolitic.txt','binary')
    console.log(result)
}

myFunction()
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks! `fs/promises` looks great

Answer (score 15):

To keep it succint and retain all functionality of `fs`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = fs.promises;

async function loadMonoCounter() {
    const data = await fsPromises.readFile('monolitic.txt');
    return Buffer.from(data);
}
```

Importing `fs` and `fs.promises` separately will give access to the entire `fs` API while also keeping it more readable... So that something like the next example is easily accomplished.

```
// the 'next example'
fsPromises.access('monolitic.txt', fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK)
    .then(() => console.log('can access'))
    .catch(() => console.error('cannot access'));
```

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: Binary mangles data, don't use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441727/309483

Answer (score 5):

There is a `fs.readFileSync( path, options )` method, which is synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const getContent = async () => {
let my_content;
try {
  const { toJSON } = await readFile("credentials.json");
  my_content = toJSON();
  console.log(my_content);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error loading client secret file:", e);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I read file by using the `Promise`. For me its properly:

```
const fs = require('fs')

//function which return Promise
const read = (path, type) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile(path, type, (err, file) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    resolve(file)
  })
})

//example how call this function
read('file.txt', 'utf8')
    .then((file) => console.log('your file is '+file))
    .catch((err) => console.log('error reading file '+err))

//another example how call function inside async
async function func() {
  let file = await read('file.txt', 'utf8')
  console.log('your file is '+file)
}
```

Comment: in your second example, `return` instead of `console.log` will not work because return cannot go with async.

Answer (score 0):

You can find my approach below:
First, I required fs as fsBase, then I put the "promises" inside fs variable.

```
const fsBase = require('fs');
const fs = fsBase.promises

const fn = async () => {
    const data = await fs.readFile('example.txt', 'utf8');
    console.log(data);
};

fn();
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of @NonCreature0714's answer

Answer (score 0):

This produces a String from the contents of your file you dont need to use promises for this to work

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync("./path/to/file.json", "binary");
```

Answer (score -2):

see this example
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readfile-method/

```js
// Include fs module
var fs = require('fs');
  
// Use fs.readFile() method to read the file
fs.readFile('demo.txt', (err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Your solution is 'sync' but question was about 'async'.