# variable not reflecting change in its value after the function callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to read data from file and then verify if the data email matches.
Once it does I use a boolean to store the value. I get output as "It matches" but the user variable is still 'false', which should become true.

```
  let user = false;
  const filename = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../users.txt");
  newvar = fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    const lines = data.split("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      fileArray = lines[i].split("|");
      fileName = fileArray[0];
      fileEmail = fileArray[1];
      filePasswordHash = fileArray[2];
      if (email === fileEmail) {
        console.log("It Matches");
        user = true;
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(user);
```

Comment: I am assuming `readFile` is `async` hence the `callback`. So your `console.log` is executing before the `callback`

Comment: `fs.readFile` is a asynchronous operation, that means, by the time `readFile` is done you are already at `console.log(user)`. You can, however, use `fs.readFileSync` to get the expected outcome BUT synchronous operations should be avoided in NodeJS because they block the Event Loop. The only time they are allowed are when you are starting an app, to load files, configurations and such and that's it.

Comment: But I really need that data that is changing inside the callback outside the function, how can I get that?

Comment: Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867517/how-to-read-file-with-async-await-properly @Lucifer you need this link.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron.

Comment: @Lucifer Given that the outside code runs before your callback is invoked, you need a time machine.

Comment: @melpomene I have tried writing await for all the function calls inside the async function, but nothing seems to work

Comment: `await` inside the callback will NOT help. You need to `Promisify` the call to `readfile`

Comment: @Bibberty how do I do that? sorry if come as bit of a noob in Javascript!

Comment: Have a look at the dupes.

Comment: @Lucifer look at the link I put above, they are doing exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line

> `console.log(user);`

is not working as you have expected because the when the function `console.log(user)` executes the value `user` isn't changed, i.e the `callback` function isn't executed yet.