# Node return byte array after turning html to pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, html-pdf

I am using the 'html-pdf' npm package to create a byte array in a nodeJs azure function. I can log and see that the byte array is being created but when i call my function i cannot get the buffer to return. My response is a 200 and again i can see the buffer if i log it to string. For context the package takes an html string and returns a pdf .How do i set the response to return the byte array?

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    if ((req.body && req.body.data)) {
        var html = req.body.data;
        context.log(html);
        console.log(html);
        var data = []
         pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
            data.push(buffer);
            context.res = {
                setEncoding: 'binary',
                // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
                body: Buffer.concat(data)
            };
          });
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs to figure this out in the future you have to create a new promise from pdf.create. My code now looks like this. This doesnt work in an azure function apparently due to GDI support for phantom js

**UPDATE**
this now works if deployed to an app service plan. Will not work in consumption plan in azure.

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');


module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    const html=req.body.data;
    var data = await returnHtmlAsPdf(html);
    var data2 = []
    data2.push(data);
    context.res = {
        setEncoding: 'binary',
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: Buffer.concat(data2)
    };
    context.done();
};

async function returnHtmlAsPdf(html) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(buffer);
        })
    });

}
```

Comment: is S1 app service plan sufficient for this?

Comment: So long as its dedicated and not consumption should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. One thing to remember though, which costed me few hours. If you use e.g. VS Code on Mac you need to make sure you use phantomjs-prebuild from some Windows deployment - otherwise it will not work. Deployment will fetch mac binaries and put it to azure functions windows, causing phantom.js to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce this issue, then I do some research and got a reliable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867517/how-to-read-file-with-async-await-properly/46867579#46867579), so I change the function a normal function(non-async) function.

Below is my test code:

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    const html=req.body;
    context.log(html);
    var data = []
    pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
    data.push(buffer);
    context.res = {
        setEncoding: 'binary',
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: Buffer.concat(data)
    };
    context.done();
    });
}
```

I use the postman to send the request, it returns a response I choose the `Save to a file`, then I open the file It's complete.

[image]

Comment: This is great but how would you get it to run async? I tried deploying this to azure and it wont work.