# How to return promise value JS

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to return a value obtained in a promise statement and I'm getting continuously Promise { undefined }, someone knows how to do it correctly?
When I render the .ejs file with the data it get's anything.

```
// /documents/vocabulary file
async function transformar() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.readFile('src/documents/Vocabulary2.txt', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
            if (data) {
                var d = data.split('\n');
                var a = []
                for (let i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
                    a.push({
                        eng: d[i].split('-')[0].trim(),
                        esp: d[i].split('-')[1].trim()
                    })
                }

                a.sort(dynamicSort('eng'));
                resolve(a);
            }
        });
    });
}

//index.js file
const vocabulary = require('./documents/vocabulary');
const myFunction = async () => {
    const data = await vocabulary.transformar();
    return data;
}
const vocab = myFunction();
console.log(vocab)

app.use('/', function(req,res){
    res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/Vocabulary.ejs'), {vocabulary_data: vocab});
});
```

[image]

Thanks for reading!

Comment: you need to await the promise.

Comment: What is `vocabulary` in `vocabulary.transformar()` ?

Comment: Since it is a promise you have to wait for it to resolve. I would replace your last line with `data.then(d => console.log('data', d))`

Comment: `transformar` does not return a promise though. need to fix the function first.

Comment: There's 2 problems here. 1) the problem everyone has pointed out, that you have to `.then` on the `transformar` call, but 2) the fact that he's trying to `return a` in the `readFile` callback, but the promise won't resolve with `a` anyway, the way it's currently written

Comment: There are 2 approaches to solve the second problem. 1) if you're using a recent version of node, `fs.promises.readFile` and all the other fs functions are available, or 2) make it into a promise yourself and `resolve(a)` instead of `return a.`

Comment: Or the third approach, use the `fs-extra` library which deals with promises out of the box

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read file with async/await properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867517/how-to-read-file-with-async-await-properly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `transformar()` method does not actually return a promise. Make sure you do that first:

```
function transformar() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('src/documents/Vocabulary2.txt', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
            if (data) {
                var d = data.split('\n');
                var a = []
                for (let i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
                    a.push({
                        eng: d[i].split('-')[0].trim(),
                        esp: d[i].split('-')[1].trim()
                    })
                }

                a.sort(dynamicSort('eng'));
                resolve(a);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here are some suggestions:

- You don't need to use `async`, since you already return a promise in the method now
- All code paths should end up in `reject()` or `resolve()`, to avoid memory leaks (like what Thomas suggested in the comment below)

Now, back to the issue of getting data out of your promise: as there is no support for top-level await, so you need to either chain a `.then()` from the returned promise:

```
vocabulary.transformar().then((data) => console.log('data', data));
```

... or use `await` in an IIFE:

```
(async () => {
    const data = await vocabulary.transformar();
    console.log('data', data);
})();
```

If the Promise is being executed in a function, then you can simply use await:

```
const myFunction = async () => {
    const data = await vocabulary.transformar();
    console.log('data', data);
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks! Now my function returns a promise and sith myFunction() I can get data, however, it get's as Promise { <pending> } when I try to manipulate this data outside the function. const vocab = myFunction(); console.log(vocab) @Terry

Comment: I modified a bit the main question @Terry

Comment: `if(!data)` the promise will never resolve. This may create a memory leak.

Comment: *"First of all, your transformar() method does not actually return a promise."* yes it does. An async function always returns a `Promise`. The same way that a function without a return statement always returns `undefined`

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! I have updated my answer to ensure all code paths will either resolve or reject the promise.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code :

```
async transformar() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Sorting data');
  fs.readFile('src/documents/Vocabulary2.txt', 'utf8', async (error, data) => {
    if (data) {
      //format data on array-dict
      var d = data.split('\n');
      var a = []
      for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        a.push({
          eng: d[i].split('-')[0].trim(),
          esp: d[i].split('-')[1].trim()
        })
      }
      //sort data
      await a.sort(dynamicSort('eng'));
      resolve(a);
    }
  });
})
}

var data;
vocabulary.transformar().then(result=>{
data = result;
console.log('data', data);
});
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter either way, but if you're returning a promise from `transformar` there's no requirement to label to function as `async`. Whether you do or not won't make a difference to the behavior of the function, I think, but I'm not sure if it's preferred to label them `async` or not

Comment: when using `then` there's no reason for `async`. when using `await` inside the function, it has to be `async`. in this case, `await` is only used inside the callback, which is correctly defined as `async`, the outer function doesn't need it in this example. i wouldn't mix `async/await` and `then` though.

Comment: You are right, async in my answer can't effect anything, but anything outside of return promise, then that will run first and can't wait for return promise.

Answer (score 1):

Your asynchronous function isn't returning anything. Also, the `fs.readFile` function doesn't return promises, it takes a callback. You should wrap it within a promise and resolve it with your final value.

```js
function transformar() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(
      'src/documents/Vocabulary2.txt',
      'utf8',
      function (error, data) {
        if (data) {
          //format data on array-dict
          var d = data.split('\n');
          var a = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            a.push({
              eng: d[i].split('-')[0].trim(),
              esp: d[i].split('-')[1].trim(),
            });
          }
          //sort data
          a.sort(dynamicSort('eng'));

          resolve(a);
        } else {
          reject(new Error('No data was found.'));
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

transformar()
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```