# Is there a cleaner way to await an https.get?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I stumbled across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867517/how-to-read-file-with-async-await-properly) while looking for a way to `await` reading a file with `fs`. I was surprised that I hadn't seen it anywhere else:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function loadMonoCounter() {
    const data = await fs.readFile("monolitic.txt", "binary");
    return new Buffer(data);
}
```

Is there a way to use `await` in the same manner shown above, but for the `'https'` library?

I didn't see anything like `.promises` and I was hoping to avoid the whole return Promise resolve reject business.

Thank you

Comment: `readFile` already returns a Promise that you can compose. The returned promise wouldn't be a member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use await in the same manner shown above, but for the 'https' library?

No, but there are numerous third-party libraries which use promises by default (including axios, node-fetch, bent, got, superagent, and urllib).