# Why is my Async Await not working in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Trying to perform a basic async/await in NodeJS but it is still going out of order.

Code I am trying to run:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var stringData;

async function find(context) {
  try {
    let text = await readFile('./sql/test.sql', context);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Try/Catch Error: ' + e)
  }

  console.log('display')
  console.log('display ' + JSON.stringify(text))
  return
}

async function readFile(file, context) {
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    fs.readFile(file, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
        stringData = data.toString()
      }),
      (err) => {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      }, () => {
        resolve(1);
      }
  })
};

module.exports.find = find;
```

When I run the above I get an undefined results for the console.log for text.

I am expecting text to use the await to populate before moving down to the console logs.

Comment: `readFile` don't return a promise afaik. You probably want to look at [fsPromises.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options) instead. I think they're relatively new so you might want to check on your node version.

Comment: @Andy That's why it's wrapped in `new Promise()`

Comment: Probably relevant: [How to read file with async/await properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46867517)

Comment: Oh, ok, got confused that the OP had used a _function_ called `readFile` too. @Barmar. I think it was still a good suggestion regardless.

Comment: Indeed. Now Node has built-in promise aware fs functions, rolling your own is just a chance to make mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not resolving the promise with the result you get from `data.toString();`
you need to add `resolve(stringData)`

PS. In the error handler you are using resolve, you should probably be using `reject` there

Comment: Also, there's no reason for `stringData` to be a global variable.