# Typescript: cannot load json file contents into array

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, asynchronous, readfile

I need load my apikeys from json file (api.json) with file structure
api.json:

```
{
"service1": ["apikey1", "apikey2"],
"service2": ["apikey1", "apikey2"],
}
```

I have a class that describes a key & value:

```
class ApiKey {
   constructor(apiName: String, apiKeys: Array<String>)
}
```

And I have a class, that loads all keys from file to Array:

```
//read file async: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867517/how-to-read-file-with-async-await-properly
    import { readFile } from 'fs'
    import { promisify } from 'util'
    import { join } from 'path'

    export class ApikeysService {

    constructor(private apiKeys: Array<ApiKey> = new Array<ApiKey>()) {
        this.loadKeys()
    }

    public loadKeys () {
        const filePath      = join(__dirname, "../../../", "api.json");
        const readfile      = promisify(readFile);
        const result        = readfile(filePath, "utf8")
                                .then(content => JSON.parse(content))
                                .then(result => {
                                    Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
                                        this.apikeys.push(new ApiKey(key, result[key]))
                                    })
                                })
        
    }

    public getKeyFor(name: String) {
        return this.keyCounters.find(x => x.keyname == name).apiKeys
    }

}
```

And my tests:

```
describe('should load api keys', () => { 
    it("should load apikeys from file", async () => {
         const service = new ApikeysService ()
         it("should load api keys for service1", () => {
    

         expect(service.getKeyFor("service1")[0]).toEqual("apikey1")
         expect(service.getKeyFor("service1")[1]).toEqual("apikey2")

    })
})
```

Test Result:

> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

```
>     Expected: "apikey1"
>     Received: undefined
```

I tried i lot of different ways to load contents from file to array in class (async also) but it wont work

Comment: You are firing an async function in your constructor, and checking the result directly afterwards - you give no chance for the promise to resolve. It is not synchronous. Either return `result` from `loadKeys` and make sure to await it, or change it to become synchronous, using `readFileSync`

Comment: Apart from the async issue mentioned in the previous comment, this code is needlessly complicated. `this.apiKeys = JSON.parse(content)` will do all that you need. There's no need to unpack the JSON object and then rebuild it into the same thing you started with.

Comment: @casraf yeap. readFileSync is works fine. Write a answer for this post, i will mark it as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are firing an async function in your constructor, and checking the result directly afterwards - you give no chance for the promise to resolve. It is not synchronous.

Either `return result` from `loadKeys` and make sure to await it, or change it to become synchronous, using `readFileSync`.

### Example 1

```
export class ApikeysService {
    constructor(private apiKeys: Array<ApiKey> = new Array<ApiKey>()) {
        this.loadKeys()
    }

    public loadKeys () {
        const filePath      = join(__dirname, "../../../", "api.json");
        const readfile      = promisify(readFile);
        const content       = JSON.parse(readFileSync(filePath, "utf8"));

        Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
            this.apikeys.push(new ApiKey(key, result[key]))
        })        
    }

    public getKeyFor(name: String) {
        return this.keyCounters.find(x => x.keyname == name).apiKeys
    }
}
```

### Example 2

```
export class ApikeysService {
    constructor(private apiKeys: Array<ApiKey> = new Array<ApiKey>()) {
        // this.loadKeys()
    }

    public loadKeys () {
        const filePath      = join(__dirname, "../../../", "api.json");
        const readfile      = promisify(readFile);
        const result        = readfile(filePath, "utf8")
                                .then(content => JSON.parse(content))
                                .then(result => {
                                    Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
                                        this.apikeys.push(new ApiKey(key, result[key]))
                                    })
                                })
        return result;   
    }

    public getKeyFor(name: String) {
        return this.keyCounters.find(x => x.keyname == name).apiKeys
    }
}
```

```
describe('should load api keys', () => { 
    it("should load apikeys from file", async () => {
        const service = new ApikeysService ()
        await service.loadKeys();

        it("should load api keys for service1", () => {
            expect(service.getKeyFor("service1")[0]).toEqual("apikey1")
            expect(service.getKeyFor("service1")[1]).toEqual("apikey2")
        })
    })
})
```