# Priority of code execution JavaScript NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I run script on server:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

async function loadData() {
    fs.readFile('ADDR To FILE\\cfg.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        map = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("1:" + serverAddr);
        serverAddr = map.serverAddr;
        console.log("2:" + serverAddr);
    });
    console.log("3:" + serverAddr);
    console.log("4:" + serverAddr);
}

var serverAddr = "NOT INIT";
console.log("5:" + serverAddr);
loadData();
console.log("6:" + serverAddr);
```

`cfg.json` file (from same folder):

```json
{
"serverAddr":"https://google.com/"
}
```

And my output is:

```
5:NOT INIT
3:NOT INIT
4:NOT INIT
6:NOT INIT
1:NOT INIT
2:https://google.com/
```

What is wrong? If I add `await` before `fs.readFile` I receive message form VS Code: `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)`

At the beginning of my program, I need to initialize global variables using `.json` file from hard disc. What is wrong? Why it is not executed in order? I expect execution 1 and 2 before 3 and 4, but with ant without `await`, console.log() 1 and 2 are at the end of program.

Comment: Perhaps you are searching for `fs.readFileSync`.

Comment: Absolutely nothing is wrong. Go through the mozilla docs and get a good read on callbacks and promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `fs.readFile` to `fs.readFileSync`

Keep in mind that these to methods can fail if you are sending a directory. Check the documentation of node [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options).

Also this question can help you
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867517/how-to-read-file-with-async-await-properly)

Comment: Yes, this is correct answer. But I don't know why await can't fix it :/